# Linux KDE SSD ERROR “SMART firmware is not reporting a failure,but there are early signs of malfunction”

Tags: kde, ssd

After upgrading my Linux KDE system to plasma 5.22, SMART Status gave me this warning:

> SSD 256GB (/dev/sda) The SMART firmware is not reporting a failure,
> but there are early signs of malfunction. This might not point at
> imminent device failure but requires longer term analysis. Back up
> your data and contact the manufacturer of the disk, or replace it
> preemptively just to be save.

The device error log contains records of errors.

After inspecting my SSD, I found no error on it. Is this a bug?

Comment: Without seeing the SMART data we can't determine it.  But you state "Linux KDE" system - either you are using Kubuntu or you are not.  Are you using Kubuntu?

Comment: Please start with OS & release. Plasma 5.22 is available in *backports* for testing purposes so issues (esp. bugs) should be reported - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs & KDE bugtracker: https://bugs.kde.org or likely best follow instructions on  https://kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-22-available-for-hirsute-hippo-21-04-in-backports-ppa/